# Display FullName from directory

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a form with a User Picker field, simple.  On my table I want to display the associated name of the user from my directory, not their e-mail address like the default is.  Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#UserPicker), the **onValueChange** event will pass an object in the **newValue**. This object is the user record in the directory. From there you can get the full name by using this:

```
var fullName = newValue.FullName;
```

For that to work, in the property editor you have to enable the **valueIsRecord** option, while the user picker widget is selected.

[image]

Comment: Where does the onValueChange go?  Is that where I am adding the record or viewing the record?  Right now I am now getting this error?  Error transforming values in binding: Cannot convert from type Directory record to String . in RequestPage.Tabs1.Request.Form1.Form1Body.UserPicker1

Comment: I am playing with this some more and have everything set.  The one thing I am unsure about is where the var is going.

Comment: @RyanBrown I'm sorry but your question is not providing the necessary information to help you. Unless you edit your question and inlcude screen shots of what you are doing and a more robust explanation, then there is not much that I can do to help.

Comment: Ok, the way I understand it is these steps. 1) onValueChange( widget:Widget, newValue:object), 2) turn on the valuesRecord in the Property Editor of the User Picker (done), then 3) you have to use the var to associate the newValue to the fullName.  What I am missing I think is where do I place the var.  I put it in the table under onDataLoad but that is obviously wrong.