# User Picker to field values

Tags: google-app-maker

Sorry if this is too basic for this site, but app maker help directed me here. I am creating a data entry screen that includes basic info for a user - name, email, phone, etc. I am using the user picker to select the individual from our Directory. How do I pass all of the needed Directory field values of the selected user to my insert record screen. I am checking the valueisRecord box on the user picker, but can't figure out how to assign the selected user's info to the form's value fields. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809480/display-fullname-from-directory/57809611?r=SearchResults#57809611

Comment: Thanks. This example stopped just at the point of answering the ultimate question, which is how do we get the data from the directory record into the data field for input. I hacked around some more and got this far:

Comment: I checked the valueisRecord box in the User Picker and entered for the Event, onValueChange(widget:Widget, newValue:String):

 widget.datasource.item.Name = newValue.FullName;


This did fill the appropriate field with the correct data, but the app stalled with the following error message:

Error transforming values in binding: Cannot convert from type Directory record to String

I could not find any posts about this error, so I am guessing this is not the correct approach. Suggestions?

Comment: I think, because your quesiton lacks many data, that you are trying to use the user picker inside a form widget that creates a record on a datasource. The datasource has a field named `Name` and you want to set the fullname to that field's value. Am I right? Please edit your question and provide as much information as possible to better aid you.

Comment: That is correct. App has 2 data models, a Cloud SQL and the Directory. The Page has the SQL database as the datasource. The Page has a Form widget with a User Picker on it with the value as @datasource.item.email. When a selection is made via the user picker I want to fill in other data fields from the SQL datasource using the Directory fields. Currently, I only have one other field on the Form, a Name field. See previous comment for scripting and results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your last comment makes sense. But please, to avoid going back and forth, I encourage you to formultae your question properly by including all the information that could be required. Now, moving on to your problem...

The reason you are getting that error is because you are binding the **UserPicker** widget value to the datasource email field. Remember, the **UserPicker** value is an object, not a string.

To fix your problem, remove the binding of the value from the **UserPicker**. Then for the **onValueChange** change event of the **UserPicker** please add the following:

```
var fullName = newValue.FullName;
var email = newValue.PrimaryEmail;

widget.datasource.item.Name = fullName
widget.datasource.item.email = email;
```

That way, you don't assing an object to the email field but instead a plain string.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I shortened it to
widget.datasource.item.Name = newValue.FullName;
widget.datasource.item.email = newValue.PrimaryEmail;