# On a simple Appmaker page - how can we retrieve data from the directory based on input with the userpicker and display it in an other field?

Tags: google-app-maker

We are high school students building an app for our school business office.  We would like to have a form where the secretary types a name in the userpicker widget - selects from the list and in the field below their employeeID show up.  There is a lot more to it than that - but that would get us started.

We have tried binding the value to an item on the userpicker as well as using a suggest box. Though we have got the employee names to show up, it only will display the names starting with A or B through the suggestion box.

We are pretty clueless... so if you have to... use crayons to describe how you might do the above. :-)

Comment: Probably this might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/58435535/5983596

Comment: I think that is in the right direction and I know you understand what I'm asking... but even though the student and I working on this are "reasonably intelligent" people :-)  there is just a small step that we are having trouble wrapping our heads around - even though I think it is staring us right in the face!  I made a really short video to describe where I think our hangup is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0hPi4GR420

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a video is better than 1000 written words. Ok, so following the example demonstrated on your video link... to populate the input field with some data retrieved form the directory model, put this in the **onValueChange** event of the **UserPicker** widget:

```
var userData = newValue;
var fullName = userData.FullName;
widget.root.descendants.fullName.value = fullName;
```

Of course, the above code can be shortened by just doing:

```
widget.root.descendants.fullName.value = newValue.FullName;
```

I just thought it would be better to explain from where exactly data is coming from. Basically, the **newValue** holds the information of the directory record which contains the **FullName, PrimaryEmail, PrimaryPhone** etc. You will need to look at all the fileds in the directory model to see what is all the information available. Therefore, if you want to fill the input with more than just the Full Name, you can concatenate data like this:

```
var userData = newValue;
var fullName = userData.FullName;
var email = userData.PrimaryEmail;
var userInfo = fullName + " - " + email;
widget.root.descendants.fullName.value = userInfo;
```

The important part to understand is that you need to know how to navigate to a widget path in order to populate that widget with a certain value. In this case, I saw that inside your page you have both the **UserPicker** and the **TextBox** widgets and that the **TextBox** widget name is **fullName**; Hence to navigate to the **fullName TextBox** from the **UserPicker** I had to first invoke the **UserPicker** widget which is defined by **widget**. Then access the **root** property which is basically the page in which the widget is located. Then access the **descendants** of the root, which is a list of all the widgets which are direct children of the page. And finally, access the **fullName** inside the descandants list. And that is why the path is:

```
widget.root.descendants.fullName
```

Think it might be helfpul to check the widgets api reference
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#Panel